# What symbol should one use for a set complement?

Tags: symbols

What symbol should I use for a set complement? It seems that the `\complement` isn't quite appropriate: it seems taller (perhaps a unary operator to appear before a set?). I guess for now `\mathsf{c}` works.

Comment: The amsfonts symbol `\complement` is often used, but there's no general consensus about an "official" symbol. I've seen it denoted in several different ways (personally, I don't like `\complement`).

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Since the notion of a complement requires a containing set, if that set has a name, say _X_, then you can simply write $X\setminus A$ where _A_ is the set for which you want the complement.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As the commenters have said, there isn't a strong consensus on this one.  Here are a few conventions I know about:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\eqn}{\[
    \stcomp{(A \cup B)} = \stcomp{A} \cap \stcomp{B}
\]}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\stcomp}[1]{{#1}^\complement}  \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{\overline{#1}}           \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{{#1'}}           \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}           \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{{#1}^{\sim}}           \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{{#1}^{\mathsf{c}}}           \eqn
\renewcommand{\stcomp}[1]{X\setminus{#1}}           \eqn

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code]

Of all of these I've used `^\complement` the most, and the overbar is the one I've seen the most. I have to say I really like your `^\mathsf{c}` implementation.

Comment: My textbooks use the minus sign, so that $X - A$ picks out the set of members of X that aren't in A. Is the minus sign commonly used for something else?

Comment: If X is an abelian monoid (i.e., has a subtraction operation) then X-A could be the set of all elements of X which can be expressed as difference of elements of X and A.  But I can't say that's a very popular usage.  I would be reluctant to use the minus sign when `\setminus` is available.

Comment: Twofeet, do you mean that your textbooks write $-A$ for the complement of $A$ or simply that they write $X - A$ for the set difference?  Either way, I suppose that $\setminus{A}$ (or $\setminus A$) would also be an option for the complement.